# Prevent UICollectionCell from centring in UICollectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, flowlayout

**Background:**
I'm building a calendar view with nested UICollectionViews.

The user scrolls horizontally between the months and the month cell height is set by the number of days or rows of days.

[image]

**Problem:**
I get an unwanted behavior when the month cell height is set to below 100px. It changes its alignment from "top" where I want it, to "center". It took me forever to figure out what was happening. The behavior can be illustrated in the interface builder:

How do I make the cell stay aligned to the top?
I have tried to create my own UICollectionViewFlowLayout but without success.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to subclass the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and recalculate the Y Position of the fields.